# Designing Automation framework for testing web application

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, batch-processing, build-automation, ui-automation

I have few web application that i need to test using automation scripts, as i am new to the automation testing i have no idea from where to start. I have to start designing the framework from scratch .
Please suggest a better architecture that i can use for the testing and that can easily be upgraded to next level.
I have to suffle between few web application and there would also be data that i need to pass at runtime using excel and the architecture have the ability to exceute the scripts in batch .
Validation: UI Validations, backend(database) validation majorly and architecture will cover all sorts of actions that are used in UI automation

I am going to use selenium(java) as tool.

Answer (score 2):

Page Object Model

It will give you way to manage and maintain your code. Now it's upto you if you want to divide your validation or function test separately using same.

For Excel file, you just need to create few classes which have the business logic to read and set the data in excel file. You can do it similarly we have done in KeyDriven framework just the difference is here you will call them when ever you need it.

Below is the reference for POM.

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

Answer (score 1):

You could start designing your framework around the [Test harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness) concept. Split your code into three major concerns([SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)):

- Execution engine - a core Selenium functionality that know only how to execute commands
- Tests

  - [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) `*.feature` files, containing the test flow
  - [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) engine that will support your Step definitions
- Specification - keeps only the environment, site and browser specifics

This model will give you a scalable and easy to maintain test framework.

> the architecture have the ability to execute the scripts in batch

All this will require a [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server to help you manage the QA process:

- [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) (and [Database plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Database+Plugin) for your case)
- [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

are the most used ones to do that.

> there would also be data that i need to pass at runtime using excel

[Data-driven testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing) is the approach that will help you achieve this. Here is [an example](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.bg/2013/03/data-driven-testing-using-java.html) with TestNG. It would be nice to organize this functionality  as a separate `TestDataLibrary` package in your project.

> Validation: UI Validations, backend(database) validation

Selenium team do suggest such [DB validation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#database-validation), skipping the Application layer. But keep in mind that not all requirements actually need to be tested via the UI. Most of the times - the [integration tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) can do the same job just fine. Some even advice to keep only the [E2E](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/7035/end-to-end-test) on the presentation layer.